# How to make Cheeze Burst Pizza same as Domino's?

Tags: cheese, pizza, restaurant-mimicry

I'm a true pizza lover and at Domino's they make a great style called ["Cheese Burst"](http://www.dominos.co.in/menu/choice-of-crusts/cheese-burst), the only problem is I can't eat it due to religious reasons.

As a [Jain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jainism), I don't eat some common foods. For more details about Jain food restrictions you can read: [this](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-rationale-behind-Jains-not-eating-vegetables-that-grow-underground-i-e-carrot-potato-onion-etc) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jain_vegetarianism).

At Domino's, they told me, "*we use a catchup sauce which is made with garlic*."

Can someone tell me:

- How to make a version of the Cheese Burst Pizza that I can eat?
- How to get that cheesy layer when you take a slice out of it?

Comment: Which elements of this Cheese Burst pizza can't you eat?

Comment: Their catchup sauce, which is the only reason of the taste from Domino's.

Comment: @Hemang people like this sauce because they like the flavor of garlic. There are a few substitutes which have a similar flavor (wood garlic, asafoetida), but if your religion prohibits the flavor itself, regardless of its source, then there is no way to make a pizza with this flavor and still keep your religious rules.

Comment: Even if you could eat garlic, it is always hard to try to reproduce chain restaurant recipes, they have it down to a science.

Comment: @huangism our comment thread has become both off topic and somewhat offensive. I'm cleaning it up.

Comment: So basically the question is how to reproduce the cheese-burst crust style at home, where you can top it with a sauce you like? There's nothing about the crust itself you can't eat, right?

Comment: @Yamikuronue, Yes, right.

Comment: Jains don't eat root vegetables, that's what is the issue. I just looked it up online. I think you can eat the taste, just not the root itself correct? For the rest of the folks, jainism is about strict non-harming of living things including bugs and microbes. Pulling root vegetables disturbs the soil and therefore many homes of these creatures. Same could be said for the leafy tops of veg, but harm is at least minimized.

Comment: From the links you cited, I'm not quite clear on _why_ you can't eat garlic, and that would effect the answer. I've seen that it is restricted both because pulling up the root kills the plant (which we can work around easily), or because the flavor dulls the mind (which is harder to fix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Experiment! If you can't have garlic, try for a tomato/italian seasoning mix. Make your own pasta sauce from scratch and substitute in or out for the things you can/cannot eat. Onion and garlic will be hard to replace, but don't confine yourself to "this is what the sauce should be." Use spices you like the flavor of. Maybe try a curry-inspired sauce?
2. The cheesy layer seems to come from a thick layer of cheese melted between the dough and sauce. If you grate mozzarella directly onto the olive-oiled bread, then top it with sauce and your second cheese, that should be enough to sate your cheese-lust! Also keep in mind that that is food-photo magic in part. Yours will most likely not look like that, but it will taste great!